# Excel add its number by 10 if column has number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas, excel-2016

[image: Example picture]

I would like to add its number by 10 for example in the screenshot, I'm trying to add '1480 on *row A490*' because the previous number was messed up, and would like excel to add its number by 10 from its previous number so, it has to be 1490, 1500, 1510 and so on, is it possible? Also I would like to leave those empty column if no number has been detected. That would be very very helpful for my future project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

1. Just write the values 1480, 1490, 1500, 1510.
2. Then, select all your values.
3. Drag the highlighted box from your right-bottom corner.
4. Move the selection as long as you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, never knew it could be done like this! It helps completing the cells below, however it works only when cells are fixed, but never worked when cells are placed randomly. Hope I make sense :)

Comment: Or just select `A471` through `A486` and then continue with step 3 from above and drag the highlighted box from your right-bottom corner.